# After the mechanical shutter of a mirrorless camera dies, can it still record videos?

Tags: mirrorless, electronic-shutter, mechanical-shutter

A similar question has already been asked [about DSLR cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/89208/can-a-dslr-still-shoot-video-after-the-shutter-dies), but it may very well be different in a mirrorless camera (please refer to [this page](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50163/why-shutter-is-not-closed-by-default-on-mirrorless-cameras-as-its-closed-on-fil)).

So here are my questions:

1. Will it still be able to record videos?
2. If it has an electronic shutter, will it still be able to take photos?

Please don't say, *Don't worry about the mechanical shutter. You are very unlikely to wear it out before it is outdated.* I don't worry; I'm just curious.

Comment: I have  a strong hunch this could vary greatly from one camera model to another, and even within the same model depending on the exact state of the shutter mechanism when it fails (i.e. open, closed, one curtain partially across the sensor, etc.). I'm not sure we really want to go down that rabbit hole...

Comment: The shutter has to be open in order for light to get to the sensor.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Which is kind of the entire point. Even if the camera would allow it if the shutter were stuck fully open, it wouldn't be of much use if the shutter were stuck closed or partially open.

Answer (score 1):

If a camera fails its self-check, it is anybody's guess whether its firmware will not refuse to operate altogether.  Also if the mechanical shutter fails, it does not necessarily do so in the wide open position.

Comment: Well, that's a good point. The shutter can fail when it is in the (semi-)closed position.